# Typescript Pick and (keyof TEntity)[], trying to create a SetFields function

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a setFields function in TypeScript, it's just a mapper to a partial class, I want to return the [Pick Utility Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys), linking the two input's types, I tried doing this:

```js
setFields<TEntity, TFields extends (keyof TEntity)[]>(array: TEntity[], fields: TFields): Pick<TEntity, TFields>[] {
  return array.map(x => {
    let result: any = {};
    for (const field of fields)
      result[field] = x[field];
    return result;
  });
};
```

But it not works, of course, because the Pick class expect a `keyof TEntity` and not an `Array<keyof TEntity>`

```
Type 'TFields' does not satisfy the constraint 'keyof TEntity'.
  Type '(keyof TEntity)[]' is not assignable to type 'keyof TEntity'.
```

My expected input/output:

```js
setFields([
  { id: 'id1', name: 'name1', phone: 'phone1' },
  { id: 'id2', name: 'name2', phone: 'phone2' },
  { id: 'id3', name: 'name3', phone: 'phone3' }
], ['id', 'name']);

// [
//   { id: 'id1', name: 'name1' },
//   { id: 'id2', name: 'name2' },
//   { id: 'id3', name: 'name3' }
// ]
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please share IEntity  and IFields interface, or expected type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are looking for something like this:

```js
function setFields<TEntity, TFields extends (keyof TEntity)[]>(array: readonly TEntity[], fields: TFields) {
// I used reduce to avoid mutation and to be more functional
  return array.map(x => fields.reduce((acc, field) => {
    return {
      ...acc,
      [field]: x[field]
    }

  }, {} as Pick<TEntity, TFields[number]>));
};


const result = setFields([{ age: 1, name: 'john' }], ['age']) // Pick<{ age: 1, name: 'john' },'age'>[]
```

To get all array values, you should use `TFields[number]` instead of `keyof` operator.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of `[number]` notation. 